# Apache Tomcat Administration Page

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

Is having an exposed Apache Tomcat Administration page a bad idea? Are there any other security risks associated with it other than the possibility of brute forcing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I certainly think it is a bad idea. There have been several security problems found with it in the past. I would never run it on a production server.

On an exposed system you want to minimize the attack surface and reduce the number of things you have to watch/patch for known vulnerabilities. This violates both of those principles.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @TheFiddlerWins it is a bad idea from the point of view of security. The less services exposed the less opportunities to compromise your system.

Think about there are tons of robots just trying to explote common bugs passing around your server frequently.

I would only expose with some cautions, like:

- Restricting access only to your IPs
- Protect with username and password
- Change the PATH (something random like /djah8hueqwy7 don't worry your browser will remember easily)

Answer (score 0):

We are all agree here to say that the less surface you expose, the less you are vulnerable to attacks.

Exposing widely an Admin page of any kind is mainly a bad idea.

Exposing your Tomcat App is enough, no need to add an additional attack surface exposing your Tomcat Admin page !

Attacks can be of multiples types and not only limited to brute force.

You could expose yourself to other types like :

- Man-in-the-middle attacks
- Malicious content injection (XSS, SQL Injection)
- Sniff and trafic recording
- Session hijacking

If you really want to expose this page, you may consider implement some security mechanism, e.g :

- Implement SSL (https)
- Limit access to a restricted number of IP adresses
- Monitor access to the admin page, to at least receive an email/sms
  when it is modified
- Log everything (access, modification)